# How to parsing some html tags content and separate them by some sepecial chars like "|"?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a variable like:

```
$content = '
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/digital_marketing">digital marketing</a>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/seo">seo</a>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/internet_marketing">internet marketing</a>
</i>';
```

how to extract a tags content like this:
digital marketing|seo|internet marketing

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the content which you are trying to access is present in `a` tag which just the child of `i`. Here i am using `DOMDocument` to achieve desired result.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/820177)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string=<<<HTML
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/digital_marketing">digital marketing</a>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/seo">seo</a>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="http://example.com/tag/internet_marketing">internet marketing</a>
</i> 
HTML;
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//i/a");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $data[]= $result->textContent;
}
echo implode("|",$data);
```

Comment: when I using xpath more accurate like: //div[@id='tags']/a have no success. Do you have any idea Sahil?

Comment: @MohammadJ Can you share `HTML`? your `XPath` is looking fine change `'` to `"` and try again.